# Where can I get a HPV vaccination in Berlin

Tags: germany, health, berlin

I will travel in Berlin and want to make a vaccination against Human papillomavirus infection (HPV).

is there some clinic in Berlin where I just can go and do it? I understand it will not be free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such clinic is [this one](https://www.sgn-berlin.de/en/news/).

It’s location:

- Wilmersdorfer Straße 98/99
  10629 Berlin

It offers a HPV vaccine.